# If $H$ is the only subgroup of order $n$ in a group $G$, must $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

We are studying some Group Theory in my Abstract Algebra class and I was thinking about this problem but wasn’t making much progress. Was hoping for some guidance is all! Thanks!

Comment: What is the order of each conjugate of $H$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? How did you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: It must even be a characteristic subgroup, mustn't it?

Comment: Show that $\phi(h) = \sigma h \sigma^{-1}$ is an isomorphism $H \to \sigma H \sigma^{-1}$. Normal subgroup means $\sigma H= H \sigma$